# Layout getBlock is always returning false

Tags: magento-1.9

I have overridden a core file with my own file. This part is working correctly.

```
<adminhtml>
    <rewrite>
       <catalog_category_tabs>MyModule_Adminhtml_Block_Tabs</catalog_category_tabs>
    </rewrite>
</adminhtml>
```

However when trying to add a custom tab with a block for content, I'm running into issues.

```
class MyModule_Adminhtml_Block_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        // ...
        // dispatch event add custom tabs
         Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_catalog_category_tabs', [
            'tabs' => $this,
        ]);

        // My tab
        $this->addTab('custom', [
            'label'   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Custom Tab'),
            'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'adminhtml/tab_custom',
                'category.custom.grid'
            )->toHtml(),
        ]);

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

The `createBlock` method is returning false.

The referenced file is at `MyModule/Adminhtml/Block/Tab/Custom.php`. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

In magento, **rewrite not means to rewrite all file under in this class**.

In there,you ***have trying to call block*** class `MyModule/Adminhtml/Block/Tab/Custom.php` using **block type**  `adminhtml/tab_custom`.

Using `adminhtml/tab_custom` block type magento  **call block**  class **`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Tab_Custom`** .And that class ***does not exit at system***.
that why you did not get false return.

### Solution

**- Define block type for your module**

define the block type of module `MyModule_Adminhtml` ,so that class this block class by  a block type:

```
<global>
<blocks>
    <mymodule>
    <class>MyModule_Adminhtml_Block</class>
    </mymodule>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
           <catalog_category_tabs>MyModule_Adminhtml_Block_Tabs</catalog_category_tabs>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>            
</blocks>
</global>
```

call that `MyModule/Adminhtml/Block/Tab/Custom.php`  by block type

```
mymodule/tab_custom.
```

So change `adminhtml/tab_custom` to `mymodule/tab_custom`